# How to get the item ID in vaadin

Tags: java, containers, vaadin, vaadin7

Good day everyone! I have a HierarchicalContainer below:

```
contFinalGrade= new HierarchicalContainer();
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("index", Integer.class, 0);
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("subCode", String.class, "");
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("courseId", String.class, "");
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("parentCourseId", String.class, "");
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("subName", String.class, "");
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("term", String.class, "");
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("studyPoints", BigDecimal.class, null);
        contFinalGrade.addContainerProperty("grade", String.class, "");
```

and I add items by using the code below:

```
Item newItem = contFinalGrade.getItem(contFinalGrade.addItem());
```

I'm wondering how to get the itemId using parentCourseId. I need to get it because I need to set the parent of some items. Thanks!

Comment: IMO You can make a hashmap entry with itemID and ParentCourseID

Comment: but how can I get the ItemId of newItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
List<Object> id = new ArrayList<Object>();

List<Item> newItem=new ArrayList<Item>();

//Do this on a button click or something maybe  
id.add(contFinalGrade.addItem()); 

//Create Items with those ids and get your property
for(int i=0;i<id.size();i++){
newItem.add(contFinalGrade.getItem(id.get(i)));

newItem.get(i).getItemProperty("parentCourseId");
```

Comment: nope. I can't do it that way since I'm adding items dynamically.. :/

Comment: Okay, I'll try and edit my post to make the code dynamic :)